# Xcode Run script warning and error message truncated

Tags: xcode, build

I've run into an interesting Xcode behaviour with run scripts where it truncates error and warning messages if it they have square bracket with text at the end of the message.

Example run script:

```
echo "warning: before [in brackets]"
echo "warning: before in brackets]"
echo "warning: before [in brackets"
echo "warning: before [in brackets] after"
echo "error: before [in brackets]"
echo "error: before in brackets]"
echo "error: before [in brackets"
echo "error: before [in brackets] after"
exit 1
```

Build log screenshot:

[image: Build log screenshot]

Is there a good reason why it does this and is it possible to quote or escape the message somehow? i've tried a bunch of different quotes and escapes without success.

I've only tested with Xcode 4.4.1.

Comment: very useful info indeed, for editing and enhancing external script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just noticed that clang output error messages are formatted like this:

```
/path:1:1: warning: incomplete implementation [-Wincomplete-implementation]
```

Which suggests that `[]` is used to categorize warning and error messages somehow, but can't figure if they are used for anything in the IDE at the moment.